# Can I call methods(instructions) in solana abi using Javascript?

Tags: web3.js, solang

I have solana abi json file.

I want to call methods in json file.

How to call methods in json and look up file ?

I only use `@solana/web3.js` and `@solana/solidity`

```
import {
  Transaction,
  SystemProgram,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  Connection,
  Interface,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Contract } from "@solana/solidity";
const solContractABI = require("../../contract/s_abi.json");
```

here is abi

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "metaplex_anchor_nft",
  "instructions": [
    {
      "name": "mintNft",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "mintAuthority",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": true
        },
        {
          "name": "mint",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "tokenProgram",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "metadata",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "tokenAccount",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "tokenMetadataProgram",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "payer",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "systemProgram",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "rent",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false
        },
        {
          "name": "masterEdition",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false
        }
      ],
      "args": [
        {
          "name": "creatorKey",
          "type": "publicKey"
        },
        {
          "name": "uri",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "title",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "address": "8Rdmrs4rUsSQKXN8VnSSSd4xEcVZTt18gydyYiU3TcjD"
  }
}
```

---

2022/07/20

I called methods when I use web3.js for ethereum.
I write down code like below.

```
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, cttAddress);

const estimateGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
    value: "0x" + value, // Only tokens
    data: contract.methods.requestMintNFT().encodeABI(),
    from: window.ethereum.selectedAddress,
    to: cttAddress,
  });
```

I want to use same function in @solana-web3.js.

---

2022/07/21

I refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474942/calling-specific-methods-on-a-solana-solidity-program.

However, I need to deploy contract to call methods in abi.

Comment: it's unclear what's going on here, you seem to have an anchor idl, but intend to use the solang solidity compiler (`@solana/solidity`)?  please clarify this question with more details

Comment: @trent.sol i'm sorry about my english is not good. I saw a medium blog. The blog says if I want to call methods in program abi, I need to use @solana/solidity.

Comment: has the problem been resolved? I encountered the same problem as you. If you see it, please reply to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON file you have is an [Anchor](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor) IDL. You can call any program from javascript that you have an Anchor IDL of with Anchor client.

In node:

```
import { AnchorProvider, setProvider, Program } from "@project-serum/anchor"
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js"

const connection = new Connection(RPC_URL);

// Set Anchor provider to local configured provider
setProvider(AnchorProvider.local());

const idl = require(<PATH_TO_IDL>);
const programId = new PublicKey(<PROGRAM_ID>)

// Create program
const program = new Program(idl, programId);

// Call mintNft
await program.methods.mintNft(...).rpc();
```

In React you also need `@solana/wallet-adapter-react` package.

```
import { AnchorProvider, Program } from "@project-serum/anchor"
import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js"
import { useAnchorWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

const connection = new Connection(RPC_URL);
const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, AnchorProvider.defaultOptions());
const idl = require(<PATH_TO_IDL>);
const programId = new PublicKey(<PROGRAM_ID>)

// Create program
const program = new Program(idl, programId, provider);

// Call mintNft
await program.methods.mintNft(...).rpc();
```

Yes, the program you are calling must be deployed beforehand. [Candy machine program](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/candy-machine/program) is already deployed in all clusters except local, so you don't have to deploy your own instance.

Comment: thx!!! I have a one more question. My project also treats with eth and polygon chains too. react-scripts: 4.0.3 is my version of library. However, @solana/wallet-adapter-react need to upgrade react-scripts: 5.0.0. It makes another library's error. If I don't use @solana/wallet-adapter-react, can there be a big error?

Comment: Please post in a dedicated question.

Comment: @man0s thx ! I solved problem I already commented.